# apply-templates select="@*|node()

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to xslt. Please help me in understand how will the flow of below xslt work for a given xml

Will the output be same as the input or will the output consist of only attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<Request>   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Envelope/body/*" /> 
</Request>           
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Comment: The output will be an error message because this is not a valid XSL stylesheet: you're missing proper XML declarations and the <xsl:stylesheet> element.

Answer (score 0):

### The flow is as follows:

- The root node, also called document, is matched, and a `<Request>` element is output.
- Matching then continues with the elements (`*`) under
  `Envelope/body`.
- The remaining two templates match any element (`*`) or attribute
  (`@*`) and output the same except without the namespace part of the
  component name.

  - For elements, this processing continues recursively
    (`<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>`) until no children remain.
  - For attributes, the value is output and processing bottoms out.

**In effect, the script is designed to output the envelope body contents, wrapped in a `<Request>` element, without namespaces.**

Comment: Should be "The root node, also called document, is matched and ..." in the first line as `match="/"` matches the root node, not the root element (which would be `match="/*"`).